# Split Columns with ' ' and Drop One of the New Columns

Tags: python, pandas, time, split

I have a csv file like this:

```
"NoDemande;"NoUsager";"Sens";"IdVehicule";"NoConducteur";"NoAdresse";"Fait";"aPaye";"MethodePaiement";"ArgentPercu";"HeurePrevue";"HeureDebutTrajet";"HeureArriveeSurSite";"HeureEffective"
    0003;"2021";"+";"157Véh";"0002";"5712";"1";"";"";"";"07/07/2015 06:30:04";"07/07/2015 06:15:48";"07/07/2015 06:32:14";"07/07/2015 06:32:23"
    0265;"0496";"+";"161Véh";"0035";"04075";"1";"";"";"";"07/07/2015 06:35:04";"07/07/2015 05:09:55";"07/07/2015 06:36:18";"07/07/2015 06:36:27"
    0004;"2208";"+";"157Véh";"0002";"5713";"1";"";"";"";"07/07/2015 06:45:04";"07/07/2015 06:32:23";"07/07/2015 06:40:05";"07/07/2015 06:40:10"
```

What I want to do:

1. Split some of the columns, making the columns with 'Date' and 'Time' into two.
2. Save only one column of 'Date' and drop the others.

And I tried like this:

```
#coding=latin-1

import pandas as pd
import glob

pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

path = r'D:\Python27\mypfe\data_test'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None,header=0,sep=';')
    s1 = df['HeurePrevue'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
    df['Date'] = s1.apply(lambda x: x[0])
    df['HeurePrevue'] = s1.apply(lambda x: x[1])

frame = pd.concat(list_)

print frame
```

It works with one column, but when I want to do the same to the second it no longer works. What should I do to make it work with all my columns while saving the others remaining the same?

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to split the subsequent columns only the first

Comment: I succeed only in splitting the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

raw_df = io.StringIO("""\
HeurePrevue           HeureDebutTrajet    HeureArriveeSurSite     HeureEffective
06/07/2015 05:30:04  06/07/2015 16:54:31  06/07/2015 16:54:35  06/07/2015 16:54:38
06/07/2015 06:10:04  06/07/2015 05:38:39  06/07/2015 06:29:51  06/07/2015 06:30:06
06/07/2015 06:10:04  06/07/2015 05:38:39  06/07/2015 06:29:51  06/07/2015 06:30:06
""")
df = pd.read_csv(raw_df, index_col=None, skiprows=1, header=None,
                 delim_whitespace=True)

df = df[[0, 1, 3, 5, 7]]
df.columns = ['Date', 'HeurePrevue', 'HeureDebutTrajet', 'HeureArriveeSurSite',
              'HeureEffective']
```

Output:

```
         Date HeurePrevue HeureDebutTrajet HeureArriveeSurSite HeureEffective
0  06/07/2015    05:30:04         16:54:31            16:54:35       16:54:38
1  06/07/2015    06:10:04         05:38:39            06:29:51       06:30:06
2  06/07/2015    06:10:04         05:38:39            06:29:51       06:30:06
```

Comment: It's not working when I want to get my columns from files, I can't use a `path` in `StringIO`.

Comment: The `StringIO` part is simply so the code is testable by a simple copy-paste-evaluate. Drop the line `raw_df = ...`, and change `raw_df` in the next one by the name of your csv file.

Comment: @ch36r5s if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.